# smarty math returns comma instead of point

Tags: decimalformat, smarty3

doing this opperation in Smarty

```
{math equation=1.1+0.7 format="%.2f"}
```

I get a result with a comma separated decimal of 1,80

No idea of how to get a 1.80 value.

Thnx so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution i have found is to replace the comma with a poin.

```
math|replace:",":"."
```

Hope it helps someone.